# A better way to change the background color using a ternary operator

Tags: react-native, styling, ternary-operator

Currently, I'm using a function to to toggle hasBeenClicked, then I use a conditional to make sure the background color is changed only when hasBeenClicked is true.  I'd prefer to use a ternary operator inside the style prop to handle the logic.

```
    let randomHex = () => {


  let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    // console.log('here is your random hex color', color);
  }
  return color;

}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      hasBeenClicked: false

    }
  }


  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      hasBeenClicked: !this.state.hasBeenClicked
    })
    if (this.state.hasBeenClicked === true) {
      this.setState({
        backgroundColor: randomHex()
      })
    }


  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor }]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.changeColor}
        >
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>


      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried

```
<View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: {this.state.hasBeenClicked: this.state.backgroundColor ? 'green'} }]}>
```

What's a better way/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary is incorrect:

`{ this.state.hasBeenClicked : this.state.backgroundColor ? 'green'}`

should be

`{ this.state.hasBeenClicked ? this.state.backgroundColor : 'green'}`

Comment: That was it.  I can't believe i screwed up something as simple as that.

Comment: We've all done it :) Usually when we've been staring code for far too long haha

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create 2 different CSS classes with different background colors. Eg,

```
.red: {
  background: 'red'
}
.blue: {
  background: 'blue'
}
```

Now in your `<View />`, you can assign the classes dynamically based on your `this.state.hasbeenClicked` value. Eg,

```
render(){
  const className = this.state.hasBeenClicked ? 'blue' : 'red'
  return(
    <View className={className}>
      // rest of your code
    </View>
  )
}
```