# Ternary Operator Inline style tag React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

In my React/Typescript application, I want to conditionally display a color depending if the value of `payload[1]` is null or not. As seen below, I have the `style` tag inline.

```
<li className="recharts-tooltip-item" style={{ payload[1] ? color : `${payload[1].color}` }}>
    {payload[0] ? `${payload[1].dataKey} : ${payload[1].value}` : ""}
</li>
```

I have tried following suggestions from, [A better way to change the background color using a ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52940380/a-better-way-to-change-the-background-color-using-a-ternary-operator), but I am getting error: Type '{ payload: Payload<ValueType, NameType>[]; 1: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'payload' does not exist in type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'

**Update of Code:**

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        <div className = "custom-tooltip">
          <ul className="recharts-tooltip-item-list" style={{padding: '0px', margin: '0px', listStyle:'none'}}>
            <li className="recharts-tooltip-item" style={{ color: payload[0] ? color : `${payload[0].color}`}} >
              {payload[0] ? `${payload[0].dataKey} : ${payload[0].value}` : ""}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: ``{ payload[1] ? color : `${payload[1].color}` }`` doesn't appear to be a valid JS expression (did you mean an object literal with a single property?), I wonder how you're not getting a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a property in the `style` prop properly. You're using the raw color value in the falsy situation. I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for

```js
<li style={{
  color: payload[1] ? color : `${payload[1].color}`
}}>
  {payload[0] ? `${payload[1].dataKey} : ${payload[1].value}` : ""}
</li >
```

For your second problem, Make your own type definition for your component. Something along the lines of this should work

```js
type CustomTooltipProps = Omit<TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>, 'payload'> & {
  payload: {
    dataKey: any;
    value: any;
    color: any;
  }[]
}
```

Comment: when I try this, on the second and third color I get error message: "Property 'color' does not exist on type 'never'"

Comment: This is an unrelated problem. You are defining your `payload` as an empty array right? You need to add the type definition for it. When you create an empty array with not type definition, it is assuming the array is (and forever will be) an empty array. So accessing `payload[0].color` will give you this error

Comment: I provide a type definition at the top of the defintion: `const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>)` Is there something else I should do for `payload[0].color` ?

Comment: also, in the `export interface Payload<TValue extends ValueType, TName extends NameType>` it defines color as having type: `color?: string;`

Comment: Update your question and show me your type definition and how you are initializing the `payload` variable

Comment: `payload` is a property (an array)  of `Tooltip` of recharts library https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip

Comment: I don't know what the type definition of recharts looks like under the hood. But ultimately, this problem is not related to how you're defining your inline styles. One thing you can do is use a type assertion to forcefully override the definition that rechart uses. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: physcially where could i put the type assertion? Would inline work, I tried: `(color as CSSProperties)` but there is still an error

Comment: @user19251203 After thinking about it more, I think making a custom type definition for the component would make more sense. Updated

Answer (score 0):

```
<li className="recharts-tooltip-item"style={{ color: payload[1] ? "red" : `${payload[1].color}` }}>
```

Can you try to write the code like this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).